# ConnectionError Exception working separately but not working with in a function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, exception, web-scraping

Below is the code to ignore invalid website which works fine if run separately, but with in a function it throws getaddrinfo error.

Code Used separately :-

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://www.chec.bj.cn')
except ConnectionError:
    print(False)
```

Output the above code generates:-

```
False
```

Code within Function :-

```
def invalid_site(url):
     try:
        r = requests.get(url)
     except ConnectionError:
        pass
     else:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
    return url
```

Error the above code generates :-

```
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me :-

```
def invalid_site(url):
     try:
        r = requests.get(url)
     except Exception:
        return None
     else:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
     if url is None:
        url=''
     else:
        url=url
     return url
```

But still not sure that why it didn't work with connectionerror exception.